# Is the permanent of the matrix $[(\frac{i+j}{2n+1})]_{0\le i,j\le n}$ always positive?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, integer-sequences, quadratic-residues, permanent

Recall that the permanent of an $n\times n$ matrix $A=[a_{i,j}]_{1\le i,j\le n}$ is defined by
$$\operatorname{per}A=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\prod_{i=1}^n a_{i,\sigma(i)}.$$

In 2004, R. Chapman [Acta Arith. 115(2004), 231-244] determined the value of
$$\det\left[\left(\frac{i+j-1}p\right)\right]_{1\le i,j\le(p+1)/2}=\det\left[\left(\frac{i+j}p\right)\right]_{0\le i,j\le(p-1)/2},$$
where $(\frac{\cdot}p)$ is the Legendre symbol. Motivated by this, here I pose the following conjecture involving permanents.

**Conjecture.** For each $n=0,1,2,\ldots$, we have
 $$\operatorname{per}\left[\left(\frac{i+j}{2n+1}\right)\right]_{0\le i,j\le n}>0,\tag{$*$}$$
where $(\frac{\cdot}{2n+1})$ is the Jacobi symbol.

Let $a_n$ denote the permanent in $(*)$. Via Mathematica I find that
\begin{gather}a_0=a_1=1,\ a_2=a_3=2,\ a_4=20,\ a_5=16,\ a_6=48,\ a_7=55,
\\a_8=128,\ a_9=320,\ a_{10}=1206,\ a_{11}=768,\ a_{12}=406446336,
\\a_{13}=43545600,\ a_{14}=141312,\ a_{15}=2267136,\ a_{16}=389112,
\\a_{17}=1624232,\ a_{18}=138739712,\ a_{19}=122605392,\ a_{20}=2262695936,
\\a_{21}=20313407488,\ a_{22}=17060393728,\ a_{23}=189261676544,
\\a_{24}=374345132371011500507136,\ a_{25}=669835780976.
\end{gather}

I don't know how to solve the conjecture. Any ideas towards the solution?

Comment: I changed \text{per}\,A to \operatorname{per}A, in particular, deleting the manually added white space to the right of $\operatorname{per}$. With \operatorname{}, the spacing to the left and right depends on the context, so that $\operatorname{per}(A)$ has less space to the right of $\operatorname{per}$ than $\operatorname{per} A$ has. That is standard usage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the sequence A322898 in OEIS.
I used a program in PARI and calculated the values of a(26) to a(34).

```
a(26) = -7000008163328
a(27) = 22712032822272
a(28) = 2244036651776
a(29) = 4363027965018112
a(30) = 30229121955004416
a(31) = -46693326700068864
a(32) = -23328907207088128
a(33) = 3173005987716005888
a(34) = 136427303851761536
```

The conjecture is **disproved**.

Comment: Can anyone explain briefly how these values were computed? (34! is huge and permanents do not behave well (no reductions available)).

Comment: I used the PARI function "matpermanent". It is faster than "Permanent [...]" in Mathematica and also faster than "LinearAlgebra [Permanent] (...)" in Maple. In tens of hours, the premanent can be calculated up to n = 36. The calculation up to n = 34 took about 20 hours.

Comment: Thanks. I am more interested in algorithmic aspects. Googling "Pari matpermanent" gave me only some advice on lippstics.

Comment: https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/dochtml/html/Vectors__matrices__linear_algebra_and_sets.html, Ryser's formula is used.

Comment: @Vaclav Kotesovec  Thank you for your further computation!